# read .resx file and display the contents in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have created an application where I have to load the .resx file and display the contents of the .resx file in the datagridview. I am loading the .resx through menustrip. I have tried using the following code, but no data show up..

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenDialog.Reset();
    OpenDialog.InitialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    OpenDialog.RestoreDirectory = false;
    OpenDialog.Filter = "Resource files (*.resx)|*.resx";
    if (OpenDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StreamReader MyStream = new StreamReader(OpenDialog.FileName); 
        BBookGrid.DataSource = null;
        m_BBookTable.Clear();  //Clear the existing table
        BBookGrid.DataSource = m_BBookTable;
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                String MyLine = MyStream.ReadLine();
                if (MyLine == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (MyLine.Length != 0)
                {
                    String[] fields = MyLine.Split(Separator.ToCharArray());
                    if (fields.GetLength(0) == NumColumns)
                    {
                        m_BBookTable.Rows.Add(m_BBookTable.NewRow());
                        m_BBookTable.Rows[m_BBookTable.Rows.Count - 1][SourceCol]
                                   = fields[0].Trim();
                        m_BBookTable.Rows[m_BBookTable.Rows.Count - 1][TargetCol] 
                                  = fields[1].Trim(); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fatal Error" + ex.ToString());
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error..?

Comment: I can open the file, but the data cannot is not displayed on the datagridview.

Comment: //Initialize everything on startup
//Create a data table with two columns
this.m_BBookTable = new DataTable(TableName);
this.m_BBookTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(NameCol, Type.GetType("System.String")));
            this.m_BBookTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(DateCol, Type.GetType("System.DateTime")));
            BBookGrid.DataSource = m_BBookTable;
//Set up a better looking table 
 BookGrid.Columns[NameCol].Width = (BBookGrid.Width - BBookGrid.RowHeadersWidth - 2 * GridLineWidth) / NumColumns- GridLineWidth;
BBookGrid.Columns[DateCol].Width =BookGrid.Columns[NameCol].Width;

Comment: The above comment contains the code to create a table and display the contents. I don't know where i am going wrong.

Comment: Try to set the DataSource after you load it with data!

Comment: Since i'm new to c# i don't know much about the language. can u give me some references from where i can learn the topic to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the DataSource **after** you have filled it with data!

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenDialog.Reset();
    OpenDialog.InitialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    OpenDialog.RestoreDirectory = false;
    OpenDialog.Filter = "Resource files (*.resx)|*.resx";
    if (OpenDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StreamReader MyStream = new StreamReader(OpenDialog.FileName); 
        BBookGrid.DataSource = null;
        m_BBookTable.Clear();  //Clear the existing table
        ///BBookGrid.DataSource = m_BBookTable;  ///  this line should be
        // down after the catch i.e. after the data source is filled!!
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                String MyLine = MyStream.ReadLine();
                if (MyLine == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (MyLine.Length != 0)
                {
                    String[] fields = MyLine.Split(Separator.ToCharArray());
                    if (fields.GetLength(0) == NumColumns)
                    {
                        m_BBookTable.Rows.Add(m_BBookTable.NewRow());
                        m_BBookTable.Rows[m_BBookTable.Rows.Count - 1][SourceCol]
                                   = fields[0].Trim();
                        m_BBookTable.Rows[m_BBookTable.Rows.Count - 1][TargetCol] 
                                  = fields[1].Trim(); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fatal Error" + ex.ToString());
            Application.Exit();
        }
        // now that is has data we set the data source!  
        BBookGrid.DataSource = m_BBookTable;
    }
}
```